# How do I delete a line only if it is at the specified line number and it matches the pattern?

Tags: bash, sed

How do I delete a line only if it is at a specified line number and it matches the pattern?

---

For example:

- I want to *delete* (`d`);
- the *third* line (`3`);
- if it's *blank* (`^$`);

---

The following syntax:

```
cat file | sed '3 /^$/d'
```

Returns the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unknown command: `/'
```

Comment: Don't you mean **third** line if it is blank?

Comment: What's the special use of `cat` in your example? Any reason to complicate things and not run `sed '3 /^$/d'  file`?

Comment: Like Kaz, I'm puzzled by the code, given the stated interest in deleting the *first* line. Pretty clearly, though, the [code is pointing to line 3](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#toc-uh-26).

Comment: I may be blind but I don't see how the answers to the linked question really showing how to combine both a line number match and a pattern match. The closest is this: `sed -i '4s/foo/bar/g' file` (substitute only on one line), but that only works since `s///` is an operation, and a no-op if it doesn't match. (So yah, voted for reopen)

Comment: FWIW, I voted to close this question as *unclear* due to the confusion over which line should be deleted (my vote was lumped in with the duplicate votes). Since tjt263's edit removes the ambiguity, I'm now voting to re-open.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
sed '3{/^$/d;}' file
```

Note the braces.

Comment: Since this answer currently contains _no_ explanation what-so-ever: Both line numbers (the `3`) and patterns (the `/^$/`) are ways of specifying how to match lines: each command can only be preceded by one way of matching. Fortunately, brackets create a group of commands that can go anywhere a single command can go. So you can do `42 { /regex/ d }`, or `/regex/ { 42 d }`, or nest them for more complex situations: `/foo/ { 1 { /bar/ d }; $ { /qux/ d } }`

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know you could use the braces like that.

Answer (score 3):

Like user000001 answered, `sed '3{/^$/d;}' file` is good enough, but it will only show you that output. If you want to modify the file, and your `sed` is the GNU `sed`, you can use `sed -i '3{/^$/d}' file` (for GNU `sed`, the `;` before `}` can also be omitted here).

> ```
> `-i[SUFFIX]'
> `--in-place[=SUFFIX]'
>      This option specifies that files are to be edited in-place.  GNU
>      `sed' does this by creating a temporary file and sending output to
>      this file rather than to the standard output.(1).
> ```

With FreeBSD/OS/X `sed`, use `sed -i '' '3{/^$/d;}' file`.